# How to set FlavorDimensions in AGP 7.0.0?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Since Android Studio Arctic Fox has reached stable recently, our team has decided to make the switch. However, we hit some roadblocks while upgrading our project to use the latest AGP,  from `4.2.1` to `7.0.0`

Below is our old `app/build.gradle.kts`:

```kotlin
android {
    
    flavorDimensions("environment")

    productFlavors {
    
        create("development") {
            dimension("environment")
            ...
        }
        
        create("staging") {
            dimension("environment")
            ...
        }
        
        create("production") {
            dimension("environment")
            ...
        }
    }
    
}
```

We managed to replace `dimension("environment")` with `dimension = "environment"`, but we are not able to use the same approach for `flavorDimensions`.

```
flavorDimensions = listOf("environment") // syntax error because it's immutable
```

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

###### Spec for flavorDimensions showing it as val, hence not assignable

[image]

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Since it's a MutableList, we can just add it directly

```kotlin
flavorDimensions.add("environment")
```

**Updates:**

Alternatively, a more favourable writing style in Kotlin:

```kotlin
flavorDimensions += "environment"
```

Comment: **You Qi** Thanks a lot, spent an hour reading carefully doc to understand why **flavorDimensions** doesn't work. Thanks **Google**

Comment: Or more kotlin style `flavorDimensions += "environment"`

Comment: This is helped but for me with different packages for flavors: R package not found.