# Android 'flavorDimensions' in build.gradle is deprecated

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

Settings in `build.gradle` `flavorDimensions "xyz", "abc"`

```
@Incubating 
@Deprecated(message = "Replaced by flavorDimensions property") 
public void flavorDimensions(
    @NotNull String... dimensions
)
```

I could not find an example of a modern approach.

Comment: I think that when something is Deprecated they should give a hint(link) to what should replace it.

Answer (score 65):

Based on the `@Deprecated` message "Replaced by flavorDimensions property," I replaced my equivalent `flavorDimensions "xyz", "abc"` instance with:

```
flavorDimensions = ["xyz", "abc"]
```

I don't entirely understand the ramifications of this, but it didn't seem to break anything in my admittedly very simple configuration, and the warning went away.

Comment: I suppose that is kotlin dsl and not groovy, right?

Comment: @David You can use `flavorDimensions = ['xyz', 'abc']` in Groovy.

Comment: after doing this, gradle sync would run fine, but when i tried to run any of the tests in any other module, i would get the error with the app module with the flavors:
`com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html`

Comment: I think this should be marked as answer. @David if you find his answer helpful and solved, mark it as the answer

Comment: Just a hint: If you still get the error message you probably forgot the '=' symbol, which becomes obligatory when you add the brackets []

Comment: Yes, the equal sign is essential in this distinction between setting a property (new) and calling a method (old)

Answer (score 29):

It looks like they change `flavorDimensions` to accept only `List` not `String`, so you need to change the code to look like this:

```
flavorDimensions = ["dimension"]
```

Or

```
flavorDimensions = ["dimension1","dimension2"]
```

Comment: This is a bit clearer and more concise than the accepted answer.

Comment: That's not what's in the [Configure Build Variants](https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants?utm_source=android-studio#product-flavors) docs. In addition it creates additional warnings `All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension`

Answer (score 21):

Just use:

```
flavorDimensions += "version"
```

This works.

Comment: Hello. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: @lgn https://developer.android.com/build/build-variants#product-flavors This is the official recommended method to configure product flavors now

Comment: That's only the kts variant, not the groovy one.

Comment: @David Kotlin is preferred over the Groovy for writing Gradle scripts now: https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl

Answer (score 6):

The flavorDimensions property in the android block is deprecated and replaced by the flavorDimensions property in the buildFeatures block. You can use the following code to achieve the same result as your original code:

```
buildFeatures {
    flavorDimensions = ["version"]
}

productFlavors {
    fsm {
        dimension "version"
        versionNameSuffix ".companyName"
        applicationIdSuffix ".companyName"
    }
}
```

You can also use the Kotlin DSL syntax if you prefer:

```
buildFeatures {
    flavorDimensions += "version"
}

productFlavors {
    create("fsm") {
        dimension = "version"
        versionNameSuffix = ".companyName"
        applicationIdSuffix = ".companyName"
    }
}
```

Comment: For Kotlin DSL, you don't need to put `flavorDimensions` in `buildFeatures` block. It can directly go in `android { ... }` block like this: `flavorDimensions += "version"`

Answer (score 4):

after updating my `build.gradle` file to using `flavorDimensions ["dimension1","dimension2"]`, i got an error while building:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> com.android.builder.errors.EvalIssueException: All flavors must now belong to a named flavor dimension. Learn more at https://d.android.com/r/tools/flavorDimensions-missing-error-message.html
```

to fix this, i had to do this instead:

```
flavorDimensions.add("dimension1")
flavorDimensions.add("dimension2")
```

*related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68661161/2898715*